# PostgreSQL-npgsql DataReader disconnection during read loop with some pause

Tags: .net, postgresql, npgsql

Environment: postgres 9.6.3, npgsql 3.2.5, .net 4.5.1

We execute an import/export transfer task (large amount of data to transfert row by row), 
that use a cursor during read and a separate connection to perform write.

What happens is that if the write operation takes a bit long (few seconds), we receive the following error in DataReader.Read();:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream ---> System.IO.IOException: 
Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<Ensure>d__27.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<Ensure>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<DoReadMessage>d__148.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>d__147.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<Read>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.Read()
```

According to the duration of the pause (3-4 seconds) we may fetch: 120, 240, ... records, and than the exception raise.
   If we do not pause the read, and we read all data in one loop, it works.

BTW we cannot read all data in memory for space allocation reason.

We see that we receive a:
    DataReader_ReaderClosed event during the failing call to DataReader.Read();

Here our PG function skeleton:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION "public"."myPGFunction" (INOUT cv_1 refcursor DEFAULT NULL::refcursor)  RETURNS refcursor
   AS $$

   begin  

      OPEN cv_1 FOR
        SELECT ....
        FROM .... a;

   end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

And the code is something like:

```
        _Connection = new NpgsqlConnection("");
        _Connection.Open();
        _Transaction = _Connection.BeginTransaction();
        _SelectCommand = _Connection.CreateCommand();

        _SelectCommand.CommandText = "myPGFunction";
        _SelectCommand.Connection = _Connection;
        _SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        NpgsqlParameter parCur = new NpgsqlParameter("cv_1".ToLower(), NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor);
        parCur.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
        parCur.Value = "refcur";
        _SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(parCur);

        _SelectCommand.Transaction = _Transaction;
        _SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        _SelectCommand.CommandText = "FETCH ALL IN \"refcur\"";
        _SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        _DataReader = _SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

here the read loop :

```
    while(_DataReader.Read())
    {
        // Read Data
        // Transfer data taking up to 3-4 seconds
        ...
    }
```

So is there any timeout to perform a _DataReader.Read() loop following an ExecuteReader() using CommandText = "FETCH ALL IN \"refcur\""; ?

BTW we tested several values of Command Timeout, or even the special "Internal Command Timeout" or TCP keep alive, etc... 
   without any effect on our issue.

Comment: There's no timeout imposed by Normal or AFAIK by Postgresql, but there could be one imposed by some network device on your side. In any case, the exception message indicates PostgreSQL closed the connection (although it could be an intermediate device), start by checking the logs on the server. If it really is some network timeout, try enabling TCP keepalive (read the docs)

Comment: Thanks Shay. Here the server log:  2017-11-26 11:50:20.458 LOG:  could not send data to client:     Connection reset by peer
2017-11-26 11:50:20.458 STATEMENT:  FETCH ALL IN "refcur"
2017-11-26 11:50:20.458 LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
2017-11-26 11:50:20.458 STATEMENT:  FETCH ALL IN "refcur"
2017-11-26 11:50:20.459 FATAL:  connection to client lost
2017-11-26 11:50:20.459 STATEMENT:  FETCH ALL IN "refcur"  Adding a keepalive doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: That's really a VPN network issue as I cannot reproduce on LAN. That's a pity I cannot test this from remote access. Tried to change several TCP parameters (windows and/or npgsql side) without any result. I see using tcpView that the connection is closed. Anyway thanks Shay

Comment: Have you tried turning on TCP keepalives (not regular keepalives) as detailed in http://www.npgsql.org/doc/keepalive.html?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately any change... still the connection goes down.

Comment: @Robert I'm also getting this error.